# jquery datepicker dateformat is not preserve

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
      my jquery date picker as below:
      $('#dp').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        beforeShow: function () { $(".ui-datepicker").css('font-size', 11) },
        onSelect: function () {   .....}'
         });
```

On date picker, i have added onselect event which fires on each select of date.
PROBLEM: initially date format shows - mm/dd/yy format. After changing the date, it appears as MMM/dd/yyyy
and not preserve date format.

Can you please suggest how i could apply my date format consistent as mm/dd/yy ?

Thank You

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BwgZ8/1/ - try to recreate the issue there..  also what are the versions of jQuery & UI used

Comment: Thanks. In my code, i wrote - MM/dd/yy which raised this issue. now, it resolved. thanks. please put in ans so, i can mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks fine... in your code you might have specified the `MMM/dd/yy` format instead of `mm/dd/yy`

```
$('#dp').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    beforeShow: function () {
        $(".ui-datepicker").css('font-size', 11)
    },
    onSelect: function () {}
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BwgZ8/)